# How to assign values to a MATLAB matrix on the diagonal?

Tags: matlab, vectorization

Suppose I have an NxN matrix A, an index vector V consisting of a subset of the numbers 1:N, and a value K, and I want to do this:

```
 for i = V
     A(i,i) = K
 end
```

Is there a way to do this in one statement w/ vectorization?

e.g. A(**something**) = K

The statement `A(V,V) = K` will not work, it assigns off-diagonal elements, and this is not what I want. e.g.:

```
>> A = zeros(5);
>> V = [1 3 4];
>> A(V,V) = 1

A =

 1     0     1     1     0
 0     0     0     0     0
 1     0     1     1     0
 1     0     1     1     0
 0     0     0     0     0
```

Comment: And I hate that guideline because it means that you don't get that context information in the title when you search.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I usually use [EYE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/eye.html) for that:

```
A = magic(4)
A(logical(eye(size(A)))) = 99

A =
    99     2     3    13
     5    99    10     8
     9     7    99    12
     4    14    15    99
```

Alternatively, you can just create the list of linear indices, since from one diagonal element to the next, it takes `nRows+1` steps:

```
[nRows,nCols] = size(A);
A(1:(nRows+1):nRows*nCols) = 101
A =
   101     2     3    13
     5   101    10     8
     9     7   101    12
     4    14    15   101
```

If you only want to access a subset of diagonal elements, you need to create a list of diagonal indices:

```
subsetIdx = [1 3];
diagonalIdx = (subsetIdx-1) * (nRows + 1) + 1;
A(diagonalIdx) = 203
A =
   203     2     3    13
     5   101    10     8
     9     7   203    12
     4    14    15   101
```

Alternatively, you can create a logical index array using `diag` (works only for square arrays)

```
diagonalIdx = false(nRows,1);
diagonalIdx(subsetIdx) = true;
A(diag(diagonalIdx)) = -1
A =
    -1     2     3    13
     5   101    10     8
     9     7    -1    12
     4    14    15   101
```

Comment: @Jason S: Thanks! I actually find this an annoying issue; I often attempt to use `diag` first, before I remember to use `eye`

Comment: for the second last examples, I suggest to use matlab's sub2ind function to find the absolute indices. In my opinion, this is the most straight-forward (and most readable) approach and could replace your last two suggestions.

Comment: @tc88: you're right in that row/column indices are more intuitive. However,  an assignment `A(rowIdx, colIdx) = -1` assigns the value to all combinations of rowIdx/colIdx. Thus, if you want to assign multiple elements of an array in one go, linear indices are the way to go.

Comment: @Jonas: I agree. That is why I suggested to use matlab's `sub2ind` which returns you the linear index for given rowIdx/colIdx

Comment: @tc88: Ah, now I understand what you mean with "absolute indices". Yes, `sub2ind` would indeed make sense that way.

Answer (score 24):

```
>> tt = zeros(5,5)
tt =
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
>> tt(1:6:end) = 3
tt =
     3     0     0     0     0
     0     3     0     0     0
     0     0     3     0     0
     0     0     0     3     0
     0     0     0     0     3
```

and more general:

```
>> V=[1 2 5]; N=5;
>> tt = zeros(N,N);
>> tt((N+1)*(V-1)+1) = 3
tt =
     3     0     0     0     0
     0     3     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     3
```

This is based on the fact that matrices can be accessed as one-dimensional arrays (vectors), where the 2 indices (m,n) are replaced by a linear mapping m*N+n.

Comment: I only saw your solution after I had submitted my edit. +1 for being faster, even though my solution is a bit more general :)

Comment: I really like the tt(1:n+1:end) method, really clean!

Comment: this should be the top solution, IMHO probably the fastest?!

Answer (score 3):

```
>> B=[0,4,4;4,0,4;4,4,0]

B =

     0     4     4
     4     0     4
     4     4     0

>> v=[1,2,3]

v =

     1     2     3

>> B(eye(size(B))==1)=v
%insert values from v to eye positions in B

B =

     1     4     4
     4     2     4
     4     4     3
```

Answer (score 2):

```
A = zeros(7,6);
V = [1 3 5];

[n m] = size(A);
diagIdx = 1:n+1:n*m;
A( diagIdx(V) ) = 1

A =
     1     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Answer (score 2):

Suppose K is the value. The command

```
A=A-diag(K-diag(A))
```

may be a bit faster

```
>> A=randn(10000,10000);

>> tic;A(logical(eye(size(A))))=12;toc
```

Elapsed time is 0.517575 seconds.

```
>> tic;A=A+diag((99-diag(A)));toc
```

Elapsed time is 0.353408 seconds.

But it consumes more memory.

Comment: I used `A(logical(eye(size(A))))=K` flexible fast and reliable

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `sub2ind` and pass the diagonal indices as both x and y parameters:

```
A = zeros(4)
V=[2 4]

idx = sub2ind(size(A), V,V)
% idx = [6, 16]

A(idx) = 1

% A =
% 0     0     0     0
% 0     1     0     0
% 0     0     0     0
% 0     0     0     1
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this small inline function in finite difference code.

```
A=zeros(6,3);
range=@(A,i)[1-min(i,0):size(A,1)-max(i+size(A,1)-size(A,2),0 ) ];
Diag=@(A,i) sub2ind(size(A), range(A,i),range(A,i)+i );
A(Diag(A, 0))= 10; %set diagonal 
A(Diag(A, 1))= 20; %equivelent to diag(A,1)=20;
A(Diag(A,-1))=-20; %equivelent to diag(A,-1)=-20;
```

It can be easily modified to work on a sub-range of the diagonal by changing the function range.