# How to create symmetric zero and one matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I need to create a 100*100 symmetric matrix that has random distribution of zeros and ones, but the diagonal should be all zeros, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a uniform distribution to generate your random numbers:

```
n = 100;
a = round(rand(n,n));
```

Now set the diagonal entries to zero ([as discussed here by Jonas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963565/how-to-assign-values-on-the-diagonal)):

```
a(logical(eye(size(a)))) = 0;
```

Symmetric component:

```
aSym = floor((a + a')/2);
```

Example for n = 5:

```
aSym =

     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     1     0     1
     0     1     0     0     1
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     1     1     0     0
```

Edit: At randomatlabuser's suggestion, added line to calc the symmetric component of the matrix and eliminated loop to zero out entries on the diagonal

Comment: Note that the current version returns a matrix that is not symmetric. Also, the loop can be avoided: `a(1:(n+1):end) = 0;`

Comment: @randomatlabuser, yes thanks for your note on this, I had forgotten the symmetry requirement. I edited my answer to include that.

Comment: @roybatty, thank you, if you like you can also remove the loop in your answer.

Comment: @randomatlabuser, thanks for your suggestion on the loop (see edit), keep up the great work!

Answer (score 3):

This is one way to do it:

```
N = 100; % size of square matrix
p = 0.5; % probability of 0s
A = triu(rand(N)>p, 1); % matrix of 0s and 1s (upper triangular part)
A = A + A'; % now it is symmetric
```