# assign value to the diagnal of a matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab

```
diag(M) = c(1,2,3)
```

say I have a matrix M 3*3, then I want to assign value to its diagnal elements, but above command line does not work why?

The errors says Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963565/how-to-assign-values-on-the-diagonal

Comment: For the [generic approach to troubleshoot this error](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20054048/983722), see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20054047/983722).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `diag` this way -

```
%%// Given matrix M
M = randi(10,3,3)

%%// Assign the diagonal elements as 1,2,3
M(diag(ones(size(M,1),1),0)>0) = 1:3
```

Output -

```
M =
     3     1     2
     3     5     8
     6     2     3

M =
     1     1     2
     3     2     8
     6     2     3
```

Answer (score 1):

you can just use linear indexing, for example, if`M` is 3x3:

```
 M(1:(size(M,1)+1):end)=[10 20 30]
```

Comment: That'd be linear indexing

Comment: right... sorry a Freudian slip... lol

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the identity matrix:

```
>> M = rand(3)

M =

    0.3922    0.7060    0.0462
    0.6555    0.0318    0.0971
    0.1712    0.2769    0.8235

>> M(eye(size(M)) == 1) = [1 2 3]

M =

    1.0000    0.7060    0.0462
    0.6555    2.0000    0.0971
    0.1712    0.2769    3.0000
```