# Easy way to generate a diagonal matrix from a vector?

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I have a vector `v` of size `1 x 5`,  and a diagonal matrix `D` of size `5 x 5`. In my example, I have `v = [0 1 2 3 4].`

**First question:** I want to put the vector v on the diagonal of `D`, so that `D(1,1) = 0`, `D(2,2) = 1`, `D(3,3) = 2`, `D(4,4) = 3` and `D(5,5) = 4`.

I wrote a matlab code for this but I am sure that there is another automatic method much less expensive in computation.
So what I wrote (and to be optimized from you) is the following:

```
    ii = 1;
    for a = 1 : size(D,1)
    for b = 1 : size(D,2)
    if(a == b)
    D(a,b) = v(1, ii);
    ii = ii + 1;
end
end
end
```

**Second Question:** After finishing the first question, I need now to check if the diagonal values of D are equal to zero. If I can find (in an automatic way) a value on the diagonal of D is equal to zero, so replace it by 0.001.

In fact this can be written in a lot of manners, for example:

```
for a = 1 : size(D,1)
for b = 1 : size(D,2)
if(a == b)
if(D(a,b) == 0)
D(a,b) = 0.001;
end
end
end
end
```

But I need another automatic method which can be very cheap in terms of computations.

Any help will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're making your life harder than necessary: you don't need two loops (one would be enough), since you only need to walk along the diagonal.
You actually don't need any loop, here; only the `diag` function.

Anyway, it may be easier to replace zero entries in a copy of `v`, and then use it to build the diagonal matrix:

```
v2 = v;              % create a copy of v (if needed)
v2(v2 == 0) = 1e-3;  % replace zero entries
```

---

**Note**: If the entries you want to replace are not exactly zero, but small floating-point values, you'll need something like this instead:

```
v2(abs(v2) < epsilon) = 1e-3;  % replace zero entries
```

where `epsilon` is the threshold below which, as far as you're concerned, the entry is close enough to zero that it can be neglected.

---

Then, since you write that `D` already is a diagonal matrix, you can simply overwrite it:

```
D = diag(v2);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have matlab on-hand right now, but I'd use a combination of the following functions:
- diag
- eye
- logical

An equivalent question was answered here:
[How to assign values on the diagonal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963565/how-to-assign-values-on-the-diagonal)

Comment: No prob. If I have the time tonight when I get home I'll give it a shoot :)